# MVC5 jquery datatables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I have a simple problem which I am unable to solve.
I just started my new .NET MVC5 project in Visual Studio 2015 and I wish to use jquery DataTables.
I used NuGet to install jquery.datatables by Allan Jardine. 
Now that I did that, i see those datatables in references, but not in wwwroot folder. 
In my wwwroot folder I have bootstrap which works fine. 
I used the same thing in MVC4, but there are Script folders and Bundles, which don't exist in MVC5.

How can I use my installed DataTables?

[References picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL40i.png)

[wwwroot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1m1k.png)

My script.js is like this:

```
alert('a');
$('#prvi').DataTable();
```

And alert is triggered, but on console view in Chrome, .DataTable() is shown as invalid.

In my _Layout.cshtml I'm referencing to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

I am completely new to MVC5 so I guess this is really trivial issue. 
Still, I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are DataTables even related to the information you've provided? I thought they were C#/ORM stuff

Comment: Same question I have already answer it try it, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418726/install-datatable-jquery-plugin-in-visual-studio/36419397#36419397](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418726/install-datatable-jquery-plugin-in-visual-studio/36419397#36419397)

Comment: @PrabhatSinha yes, this is the way to use it in MVC4. And there it works.
However, in MVC5 i can't seem to get $('#id').DataTable(); to work.
I have copied valid DataTable HTML, but JQuery is shown as invalid, meaning that my Datatables.js is not linked correctly

Comment: @Cubelaster i have already used in my project its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't give any further details about your code, perhaps it's a simple typo.  the DataTables initializer is actually camelCase.  so try:

```
$('#prvi').dataTable();
```

Lowercase "d"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried that but the result is the same. The console in browser says that it's unrecognised. As if I don't have dataTables.min.js in my solution.

Comment: Posting your Razor view code might help.  You haven't provided much info here.